# SQL Query Wont Update View Count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have setup a PDO script and this is the main bit of the code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $getSavedHolviewsays = $db->prepare("UPDATE tvinfo SET views = views + 1 WHERE imdbid = :views");
    $getSavedHolviewsays->execute(array(
    ':views' => $_GET['views']));
```

But for some reason its not adding 1 to the view column for the idmdb id.
This is my table:
http://gyazo.com/d9fc6cfed3de8536b305d6b36f103520

It doesnt add 1 to the views count. Ignore about the download count. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your raw SQL query work directly against the database without using PDO ? I think you also need an additional step to binding the parameters. Not sure if `execute()` is a custom function you created or a PDO function.

Comment: Never mind. Your code looks correct. You might want to wrap the PDO code into a try/catch block to see if you get any errors. Look at this example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#117321

Comment: Its already wrapped around a try tag/catch block. I think the problem is the query

Comment: Its working fine with other querys just not this one

Comment: Are you sure that `$_GET['views']` value is valid ?

Comment: Yh, ok strange enough it started working automatically, I edited absolutely nothing at all didnt even open the file. Very odd.